# running multiple instances of a spark app on mesos through marathon

Tags: spark-streaming, mesos, marathon

I am trying to run a spark streaming app through marathon on mesos and this job eventually stores some counts into an instance of cassandra. My question is should I set number of instances (on marathon) for this app to 2 (for HA); however, the issue is wouldn't the 2nd instance be just a replica of the first one and processing and results would be duplicated?

Comment: Are you using Mesos or Docker as containerizer?

Answer (score 0):

No you don't set the number of instances to 2 for HA. Marathon will re-start any app that due to whatever reasons has gone down. It is a good practice to implement [health checks](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/health-checks.html), though.